# Direction of the z-scores in randomForest

Tags: random-forest

I wonder if someone could help me with the interpretation of the "z-scores" (%IncMSE) in the random forest approach. I am using a randomForest library in R. Specifically, I am not sure whether the sign of the score (-/+) can be possibly interpreted as a direction of the effect of a predictor on the outcome variable?

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. Yes, I was certainly aware of the caveats with the interpretation of the so-called "z-scores." As far as the signs are concerned, I am still a bit confused. One of my predictors appears fairly important based on the Increase in Node Purity statistic (importance(model,scale=FALSE). Yet, it appears to have a negative "z-score" in the %IncMse (importance(model,scale=TRUE). Am I correct in my understanding that there might not be a perfect overlap between these two statistics? If so, which one would be a more robust one for making inferences about the importance of

Comment: The partial dependence plots sound interesting. The caveat is that my predictors are categorical. Could this be a problem here?

Comment: Welcome to the site, @pdv. This is not an answer to your question. Please only use the "Your Answer" field to provide answers. Also, please merge your accounts as discussed on our [help page](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help), then you will be able to comment on your own question. Since you are new here, you may want to read our [about page](http://stats.stackexchange.com/about), which has information for new users.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @pdv. This is not an answer to your question. Please only use the "Your Answer" field to provide answers. Also, please merge your accounts as discussed on our [help page](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help), then you will be able to comment on your own question. Since you are new here, you may want to read our [about page](http://stats.stackexchange.com/about), which has information for new users.

Comment: @pdv yes, the partial dependence can also be done on categorical variables. It must be done carefully though, I re-encourage you to read about it before using it seriously. Also, answers have their own space under them for comments. Please use this and definitely listen to gungs advice.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, those importance scores are not Z-scores (assuming you talk about the thing that comes out from `importance(model,scale=TRUE)`) in pivot sense; they are a mean of error increase over trees divided by its standard deviation, but the distribution is not normal so you can't say that the value >3 is significant or anything like this.

The sign does not mean effect direction; negative importance simply means that disturbing certain attribute improves the model. This is somewhat a counter-intuitive effect and usually happens if the attribute is a pure noise or when the whole model is weak or overfitted.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is measuring the partial dependance, from the vanilla random forest r implementation manual:

> Description Partial dependence plot gives a graphical depiction of the
>   marginal effect of a variable on the class probability
>   (classification) or response (regression).

You can also find a little more formal description there. This can be a little tricky to use correctly so read about it a bit. This is an example provided there on the iris data set:

```
data(iris)
set.seed(543)
iris.rf <- randomForest(Species~., iris)
partialPlot(iris.rf, iris, Petal.Width, "versicolor")
```

[image]